# Can I mitigate Spotify's memory leak?

Tags: firefox, spotify

I need to use Spotify's web player because I cannot install the player on my work PC. Unfortunately I have noticed that after 30 mins - 1 hour of continuous play, Firefox starts lagging; a few moments later it either completely crashes or freezes.

Most of the times I solve by terminating FF from Windows task manager (ok, task manager is not the most reliable method, but it can provide an idea of what is going on) and when I do so, I find that FF is using 60-70% or the available RAM.

I never experience this behaviour when I am not using Spotify, making me suspect that the site is leaking memory.

Is there some option in the website (or some other method, maybe with Greasemonkey?) that can solve or mitigate this problem?

Comment: I also have this problem since a few weeks. I suspect it is because of an update to play.spotify.com javascript code that is leaking some objects in memory for each song you play.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and disabling my ad-blocker solved it.

See [this issue](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/The-web-player-leaks-memory/td-p/1332839) for more information.

Accepted solution from the above link (by user [sgsfbvgsfvfrghe](https://community.spotify.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/4965585)):

> I looked a bit more into this after reading reports of the VW advertisement causing issues. After de-activating my ad-blocker (uBlock origin), memory seemed a lot stabler.

Comment: Adding essential  content of the link would be more helpful for future reader.

Comment: @serenesat OK, edited my answer. Sorry for being lazy...

Comment: I have tested this approach for a while now. I am sorry to report that it has not helped me.

Comment: @Federico Sorry to hear that. It did work for me. By the way, the problem no longer occurs for me either (Firefox 47), not even with AdBlock on.